# Android realm.io variables not set?

Tags: android, database, realm

I am having trouble using a query in realm.io. My code:

```
    public static void delete(Context context, Workday workday) {
       Realm realm = getRealm(context);
       realm.beginTransaction();
       RealmResults<Workday> workdays = realm.where(Workday.class)
            .equalTo("date", workday.getDate())
            .equalTo("hours", workday.getHours())
            .equalTo("minutes", workday.getMinutes())
            .findAll();
       workdays.remove(0);
       realm.commitTransaction();
}
```

Debug:

[image]

Why is the data visible in the JSON line but not in the fields itself? What am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE:**

This is my delete function and it does find the workday1 object:

```
public static void delete(Context context, Workday workday) {
    Realm realm = getRealm(context);
    realm.beginTransaction();

    Workday workday1 = realm.where(Workday.class)
            .equalTo("date", workday.getDate())
            .equalTo("hours", workday.getHours())
            .equalTo("minutes", workday.getMinutes())
            .findFirst();

    workday1.removeFromRealm();
    realm.commitTransaction();
}
```

[image]

When it executes the removeFromRealm method it crashes:

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal State: Row/Object is no longer valid to operate on. Was it deleted?

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

You're doing nothing wrong! :)

Realm proxies your objects so that there won't be copies of your data all over the place. The getters and setters are overridden by the proxy classes and access your data directly in Realm. Of course this makes it harder to inspect the objects during debug, as you could notice, but that's why we've also overridden `toString()` to show something meaningful.

Comment: So why is this query returning 2 results? I think it should only return the one on 12 dec.

Comment: Because you're hitting a bug we fixed in 0.75.1 :)

Comment: Ah ok, I am updating my gradle build file first thing in the morning.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27331518/android-realm-io-row-object-is-no-longer-valid :)