# Android realm.io: Row/Object is no longer valid

Tags: android, database, realm

This is my delete function and it does find the `workday1` object:

```
public static void delete(Context context, Workday workday) {
    Realm realm = getRealm(context);
    realm.beginTransaction();

    Workday workday1 = realm.where(Workday.class)
            .equalTo("date", workday.getDate())
            .equalTo("hours", workday.getHours())
            .equalTo("minutes", workday.getMinutes())
            .findFirst();

    workday1.removeFromRealm();
    realm.commitTransaction();
}
```

[image]

When it executes the `removeFromRealm` method it crashes:

**`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal State: Row/Object is no longer valid to operate on.`** Was it deleted?

How can I fix this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE (I can print the content returned by the following method):**

```
    Workday workday1 = realm.where(Workday.class)
            .equalTo("date", workday.getDate())
            .equalTo("hours", workday.getHours())
            .equalTo("minutes", workday.getMinutes())
            .findFirst();

    System.out.println("--------------------------------");
    System.out.println(workday1.getHours());
```

[image]

Comment: Can you access the object ok before the removeFromRealm()? e.g. print it?

Comment: Yes I can, check my update please.

Comment: If this is something you can replicate, I suggest you create a github issue at https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to remove an object you have not committed to the Realm yet.

In this particular case, if for some reason you don't want to commit the object anymore, you can simply cancel the transaction.

Comment: I query the object and then I try to delete it within the transaction. I don't see what I am doing wrong, just following the documentation: http://realm.io/docs/java/0.75.0/#deletion

Comment: Which version of Realm are you using? It may be that you're using the close() method where it's not needed

Comment: I am using the following in my gradle build: io.realm:realm-android:0.75.1

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue. Can you provide an example project triggering this issue?

Comment: I made my repo public: https://github.com/Jdruwe/Overtime, the delete method can be found under the WorkdayUtil class. You can trigger it by deleting an added calendar item.

Comment: You are calling `cancelTransaction()` instead of `commitTransaction()` here: https://github.com/Jdruwe/Overtime/blob/master/app/src/main/java/adevador/com/overtime/data/WorkdayUtil.java#L84

Comment: This is me trying to fix the error :D I get the same error using commitTransaction()

Comment: No I did not :( I removed realm from my app and started using another system.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the problem was that the same Object I was deleting was in an Adapter. After I made the Adapter extend RealmBaseAdapter the problem stopped.